Is "most probable probability distribution" a thing?
I wonder if one can, in a useful way, assign a probability distribution to a number of possible outcomes given only some mean values.
For example, imagine I have a coin but it might be an unfair one. Let's say probability of getting heads in $p$, then probability of getting tails is $1-p$. Let's say we count heads as $+1$ and tails as $-1$. This way the mean value after $N$ tosses of the coin is $M = Np - N(1-p) = 2Np - N$. So if I known $M$ and $N$ I can find out $p$.
Now imagine rolling a 6-sided unfair die. In the similar situation, given only the mean value $M$ and total number of rolls $N$, I cannot extract probabilities of individual sides $p_1, p_2, ..., p_6$. Obviously, I can take any numbers as long as $p_i >0, p_i \le 1, \sum_ip_i = 1$ and value for $M$ is correct. However, I wonder if there is "the most probable" probability distribution or something like that?
What if I'm given more information: e.g. the mean value and the variance?

I think one relevant term is " sufficient statistic" and another is "likelihood"

@user619894 sorry if I missed something, but do I need some model for the distribution before hand? basically, should I have $p_i = f(i, \lambda)$ where the model $f$ is known, but parameters $\lambda$ are not? So I need to find best $\lambda$. That's fine, but I wonder how should I pick a model? Is there any "best" way to do that?

In practice, context often hands you the form of the distribution, though not the actual parameters.  In that case, maximum liklihood or similar techniques can help you use observed data to populate the parameters.

Look up the concept of a “maximum entropy” probability distribution.

I think your best bet would be some information on the physical causes of the imbalance. For example if you assume that the  center of gravity of the dice is off-center, you can create a model of the PDF and maybe even determine the location of the center of gravity from the mean.
